# Loop through string character by character in cmd/batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am wishing to get rid of all special characters in folder names within a specific directory.

I was thinking that I could translate each character into its ASCII character value and if its not in the range of 'normal' characters I would replace it.

I couldn't find anything which shows me how to loop through every character in a string.

```
for /d %%i in (C:\temp\*) do (
    echo before %%~ni
    for CHAR in %%~ni do (
        if CHAR < 33 || CHAR > 126 (
            CHAR = 95
        )
    )
    echo after %%~ni
)
echo Ende
```

Comment: What is your plan if the replaced character(s) results in a name that already exists? Is it not possible to live with these existing, valid characters?

Comment: `for /F delims^=^ eol^= %C in ('cmd /U /C dir /B /A:D C:\temp\* ^| find /V ""') do @echo/%C` (in Command Prompt, double `%` in a batch file) would loop through all characters; getting their ASCII is not quite trivial; anyway, perhaps it's easier to [substitute](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) unwanted characters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to provide a batch file version which uses PowerShell 2.0 *(to make it compatible with Windows 7 systems)*. It works by using hexadecimal characters instead of the decimal ones you mentioned in your question, *i.e. `ASCII 33 = Hex 21`, `ASCII 126 = Hex 7E`*, which I'm replacing with the underscore character, **`_`**, as in your example:

**Batch file**:

```bat
@PowerShell -NoP "GCI 'C:\temp'|"^
 "?{$_.PSIsContainer -And $_.BaseName -Match '[^\x21-\x7E]+'}|"^
 "%%{RnI $_.FullName ($_.BaseName -Replace '[^\x21-\x7E]+', '_') -Wh}"
@Pause
```

The above uses `-WhatIf`, *(shortened as `-Wh`)*, to show you what would happen without actually doing it. If you're happy with the output you can remove  `-Wh` and the last line, `@Pause`.

Of course you could forget about running it from a batch file and do this directly as a **PowerShell script**, *(unshortened to help you understand what's going on)*:

```ps1
Get-ChildItem 'C:\temp' |
    Where-Object {
        $_.PSIsContainer -And $_.BaseName -Match '[^\x21-\x7E]+'
    } | ForEach-Object {
        Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ($_.BaseName -Replace '[^\x21-\x7E]+', '_')
    }
```

Unlike the batch file example, I have not included the `-WhatIf` statement, so **be warned that running this will rename the directories**.

---

***Note***:

*These solutions do not take account of any existing directories already holding the name you're wishing to rename to. If such a scenario is likely to exist, you will need to improve upon what I've posted moving forward.*

---

**[Edit /]**

If you only want to view the directory names in existing and replaced formats, and not actually do any renaming, perhaps you would prefer a different layout.

This one just shows them one above the other in different colors:

```bat
@PowerShell -NoP "GCI 'C:\temp\test'|"^
 "?{$_.PSIsContainer -And $_.BaseName -Match '[^\x21-\x7E]+'}|"^
      "%%{Write-Host($_.BaseName)-F Red;Write-Host($_.BaseName -Replace '[^\x21-\x7E]+', '_')-F Cyan}"
@Pause
```

And the .ps1 version:

```ps1
Get-ChildItem 'C:\temp\test' |
    Where-Object {
        $_.PSIsContainer -And $_.BaseName -Match '[^\x21-\x7E]+'
    } | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host $_.BaseName -ForegroundColor Red
        Write-Host ($_.BaseName -Replace '[^\x21-\x7E]+', '_') -ForegroundColor Cyan
    }
```

Comment: Thanks works great, because i don' t want to rename folders i only display them.

Why i need the first function, i passed it and works great

Answer (score 0):

This will not take care of duplicate directory names being generated. This loops over the directory names and allows only letters, numbers, underscore, and space. Anything else becomes a '-'. To change the allowed characters, change the regex after the `-match`.

When you are confident that the rename will be done as you desire, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Rename-Item` cmdlet.

```
powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem | " ^
        "Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | " ^
        "ForEach-Object { " ^
            "$a = $_.Name.ToCharArray(); " ^
            "$s = $null; " ^
            "foreach ($c in $a) { " ^
                "if ($c -match '[\w ]') { $s += $c} else { $s += '-'} " ^
            "} "^
            "if ($s -ne $_.Name) { " ^
                "Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $s -WhatIf " ^
            "} " ^
        "}"
```

Naturally, this is easier if you write a PowerShell script.

```
Get-ChildItem |
    Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } |
    ForEach-Object {
        $a = $_.Name.ToCharArray()
        $s = $null
        foreach ($c in $a) {
            if ($c -match '[\w ]') { $s += $c} else { $s += '-'}
        }
        if ($s -ne $_.Name) {
            Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $s -WhatIf
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, using CMD and powershell combination

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set POWERSHELL=c:\windows\system32\windowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell

PATH=C:\
echo %PATH%

for /F %%I in ('dir /A:-D /b %PATH%') DO (
    set STR=%%I
    echo !STR!
    :loop
        set CH=!STR:~0,1!
        echo Character is: !CH!

        for /F "usebackq" %%F in (`!POWERSHELL! [int][char]"'!CH!'"`) DO (set VAL=%%F)
        echo ascii value: !VAL!

        set STR=!STR:~1!
        if "!STR!" == "" (goto end) 
    goto loop
)

:end
echo Done!
```